# Characteristic of a Ring Problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ be a ring such that $\underbrace{1+1+\dots+1}_{n}=0$ for natural number $n\geq 2$. If $a\in A$ and there exists natural number $k$ such that $a^k=a+1$, prove that there exists natural number $m$ such that $a^m=1$.

My handwork so far:
The problem implicitly tell that $A$ has multiplicative identity $1$. Moreover, if $n$ is minimum number such that $\underbrace{1+1+\dots+1}_{n}=0$, then $char(A)=n$. It imply $Order(A)=nc$ for natural number $c$.

Could I try this idea ?
\begin{align*}
a^k&=a+1\\
a^k-a&=1\\
a(a^{k-1}-1)&=1
\end{align*}
Hence, $a^{k-1}-1$ is multiplicative inverse of $a$.

By $n.1=0$, we have $n.a=0$, $na^{k-1}=0$ and $n(a^{k-1}-1)=0 \iff na^{k-1}=n$. But it means $n=0$.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Yes, your mistake in the very last step is to confuse $n.1$ in the ring with $n$ in the integers.

Comment: Why it is wrong ? Is it wrong that $1+1+\dots 1=n.1$ ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I thought you meant to conclude that $n = 0$ in the integers.  You already knew from the first line of your post that $n.1$ in the ring is zero, by assumption.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: No, in fact at the moment I don't see the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f \in Z_n[x]$ be defined by $f(x) = x^k - x - 1$.

Let $B$ be the subring of $A$, generated by $a$.

Then every element $b \in B$ can be expressed in the form $b=g(a)$, where $g \in Z_n[x]$, and moreover, we can take $g$ such that $\text{deg}(g) < k$, else, since $f$ is monic of degree $k$, we can replace $g$ by its remainder when divided by $f$.

There are exactly $n^k$ polynomials in $Z_n[x]$ of degree less than $k$, hence the ring $B$ is finite.

Thus, the elements $1,a,a^2,a^3,...$ can't be distinct, so we must have $a^j = a^i$, for some $i,j$ with $0 \le i < j$.

As you noted, $a$ is invertible, hence, from $a^j = a^i$, we get $a^{j-i}=1$, which proves the claim.

With regard to your question about $n=0$, in the context where you obtained that result, the symbol $n$ represents the element $n$ in the ring $A$, and you already know it's zero, so it yields no new information.

Comment: Could you explain me how your work in line 3 until 6. I still don’t get it that you said we can replace $g$ by its remainder. Thank you.

Comment: Long division of polynomials. Since $f$ is monic, we can write
$$g(x) = q(x)f(x) + r(x)$$
where $q,r \in Z_n[x]$, and $\text{deg}(r) < k$. But then we get
$$g(a) = q(a)f(a) + r(a)$$
hence, since $f(a)=0$, we get $g(a)=r(a)$,

Comment: Then, why every element in subring $B$ can be expressed in the form $b=g(a)$ ?

Comment: Because $B$ was defined as the subring  of $A$ generated by $a$ (i.e., the smallest subring of $A$ which contains $a$). The smallest subring of $A$ which contains $a$ is the set of elements of $A$ which can be expressed as a polynomial in $a$, with coefficients in $Z_n$.

Comment: Thanks, it’s a nice observation. I want to ask last questions, do you exploit the $n.1=0$ assumption ? I thought you don’t use that assumption. Then, why it was correct you choose $\mathbb{Z}_n$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: It's precisely because $(n)(1) = 0$ in the ring $A$, that we can reduce any integer coefficient to its residue, mod $n$, hence integer coefficients can be regarded as elements of $Z_n$,

Comment: Thank you quasi, I understand all of your explanation.